# retrieve the empty picture if the user has nothing

Tags: c#, linq

It is such when I collect my user from the database. so the user has an image is displayed while those who have nothing to be shown that they have no picture,

I've done like this in the code

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterBrugere" runat="server" ItemType="LinqData.brugere">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 isotope-item" style="float:left;">
                <div class="portfolio-item img-thumbnail">
                    <a href="../profil/profil.aspx?id=<%# Item.Id %>" class="thumb-info">
                        <img src="../profil-img/<%# Item.img %>" alt="<%# Item.fornavn %> <%# Item.efternavn %>" style="min-height:245px; max-height:245px;"/>
                        <span class="thumb-info-title">
                            <span class="thumb-info-inner"><%# Item.fornavn %> <%# Item.efternavn %></span>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

into aspx.cs I have written it here,

```
RepeaterBrugere.DataSource = db.brugeres.OrderByDescending(AY => AY.fornavn);
    RepeaterBrugere.DataBind();
```

Comment: Do you want to show no picture at all or a blank picture you have in a directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save the images, the default image of an empty picture (i.e. empty.jpg) should be saved to the database. When a user uploads a valid picture this gets overwritten. Can you update your existing data to reflect the empty picture? Another option is to modify your code behind to do a case statement or loop the results before binding and update any that do not have an imnage to the empty.jpg image.

Comment: I have done as you describe it is that I have set it up to the user to be assigned name of the tome picture while he / she can not do it. I hope you will give me a +1 for questions.